# Java Map - log message when key is not found in getOrDefault

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, List<SomeClass>> someMap` and I'm retrieving the value based on `someKey` and for each element of the list of SomeClass I'm performing other operations.

```
someMap.getOrDefault(someKey, new ArrayList<>()).forEach(...)
```

I also want to be able to log messages when I don't find `someKey`. How would I be able to achieve it optimally? Is there any other function/way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("b");
map.put("a", l);
```

Yes, you can do it in a single statement. Use [`.compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

```
map.compute("a", (k, v) -> {
    if (v == null) {
        System.out.println("Key Not Found");
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return v;
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

There's also `computeIfAbsent()` which will only compute the lambda if the key is not present.

---

Note, from the documentation:

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current
>   mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping).

This will add the key which was not found in your map.

If you want to remove those keys later, then simply add those keys to a list inside the if and remove them in one statement like this:

```
map.keySet().removeAll(listToRemove);
```

Comment: But the thing is, this method will update the map. Running the same thing for a key which had no corresponding value before will now have an empty list associated with it. So, it will not print "Key not found" twice, but once.

Comment: @HarshalParekh I find your solution smallest and easiest to understand, but since the map is large in my case, I don't think it'll be wise to mutate map for each failed get operation. As Naman mentioned in a comment below I'll have to use wrapper function. Thanks for your help

Comment: For most immutable maps, the `compute…` methods will throw an exception unconditionally, even when the key is present. That’s a fundamental difference to `getOrDefault`. Further, collecting the absent keys, to remove them later, makes a complicated solution even more complicated. Compare with a straight-forward `List<String> list = map.get(key); if(list == null) System.out.println("Key Not Found"); else list.forEach(action);` It’s not only simpler, it avoids the unnecessary creation of a dummy `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function to do that. For example, I created a function which will get the value from the map, return it if it is not null, or an empty list otherwise. Before returning the empty list, you can run a `Runnable` action. The main benefit of that is that you can do more than just logging there.

```java
@Slf4j
public class Main {

    public static Collection<String> retrieveOrRun(Map<String, Collection<String>> map, String key, Runnable runnable) {
        final Collection<String> strings = map.get(key);
        if (strings == null) {
            runnable.run();
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            return strings;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Collection<String> strings = retrieveOrRun(map, "hello", () -> log.warn("Could not find a value for the key : {}", "hello"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two choices:

Either you use a wrapper method, doing the actual call (`getOrDefault`, etc) and handling missing keys.

```
public static <K,V> V getOrDefault(Map<K,V> map, K key, V defaultValue) {
  V value = map.get(key);
  if (value == null) {
    logMissingValue(key);
    return defaultValue;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Or you create new implementation of `Map` doing just that, with a delegation to method that should be delegated (I won't do here in this example, but Eclipse work pretty well: `Alt + Shift + S` > *Create delegate methods*):

```
class LoggerMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
  private final Map<K,V> internal;
  public LoggerMap(Map<K,V> internal) {
    this.internal = Objects.requireNonNull(internal, "internal");
  }

  @Override
  public V getOrDefault(K key, V defaultValue) {
    ... if not found logMissingValue(key); ...
  }
}
```

Now about which is optimal, that depends on your needs: if you know you will always use the wrapper method, then your missing keys will always be logged. Creating a new map implementation would be overkill.

If your need is to log absolutely all missing keys - even if foreign code (for example, some API taking a map as a parameter), then your best choice is a map implementation:

- In terms of performance, I don't think you should worry about delegation: I did not test it using a benchmark, but the JVM should be able to optimize that.
- There are other parts where a key might return a missing value (eg: `remove`, `get`, ...), using such an implementation will allow you to easily trace those as well.